# JavaScript all links on a page with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, node.js

I'm trying to extract all links on a web page that has the following markup:

```
<a href="/item/0/100">0</a>
<a href="/item/1/100">2</a>
<a href="/item/2/100">3</a>
<a href="/item/3/100">4</a>
<a href="/item/4/100">5</a>
```

Basically returning all the `/item...` paths.  I have the dom object that contains this.  Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Using jQuery with Map returns (truncated)

```
    http:undefined
    { '0': '/item/200/13/0',
      '1': '/item/200/1/0',
      '2': '/item/200/4/0',
      '3': '/item/200/5/0',
      '4': '/item/200/11/0',
      length: 4,
      prevObject: 
       { '0': 
          { _ownerDocument: [Object],
            _childNodes: [Object],
            _attributes: [Object],
            _nodeName: 'a',
            _childrenList: null,
            _version: 3,
            _nodeValue: null,
            _parentNode: [Object],
            _readonly: false,
            _tagName: 'a',
            _created: true,
            _attached: true,
            _attachedToDocument: true },
         '1': 
...
```

Comment: Don't do it with regex, use [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) methods

Answer (score 7):

Newer browsers:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/item/"]');
```

Older browsers:

```
var links = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var a = elements[i];

    if (a.getAttribute('href').indexOf('/item/') === 0) {
        links.push(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have added, I'm doing this server side after a request, I have access to jQuery can parse it with that, is there a jQuery method? 'document' isn't available.

Comment: Well, you'll have to parse the HTML somehow.

Comment: Hm, So, I tried using `$('a[href^="/item/"]')`, but I can't seem to ge the value.  I guess it's a little more complicated than my post led on.  It's on node.js using the request module and the node-crawler, a jQuery object is returned that I'm using to work with the dom now, but maybe there's some other nuances associated.

Comment: @dave: You'll get the elements. If you want the attributes, then just do `$('a[href^="/item/"]').map(function() { return this.href; });` to get an array

Comment: @Blender Thanks, it's getting closer, but still odd.  I edited my post to include the results from using the map.  It returns the links in an object with 'http' undefined, but then also returns additional attributes for each object.

Comment: If you are doing it server side then you could use [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) and one of its modules like [Parse::HTML](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/Parser.pm). There maybe other alternatives like an Apache module (if you are using Apache).